# Assign Type to Snapshot Returned in Firebase's Trigger Function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a trigger function using Firebase Cloud Functions in TypeScript, and would like to assign the type of the data held in the snapshot directly in the `onCreate` function as such:

```
import { firestore } from "firebase-functions/v1"
import { QueryDocumentSnapshot } from "firebase-functions/v1/firestore";

interface PaymentDocumentInterface {
    amount: number;
    benefactorDetails: {
        email: string;
        marketingConsent: boolean;
    };
}

exports.updateDonationProjectAggregations = firestore.document('protectedEnvironmentData/financialData/payments/{paymentId}').onCreate(async (snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot<PaymentDocumentInterface>, context) => {
    console.log(`Processing payment with value: ${snapshot.data().amount}`);
});
```

When I attempt to do so, TS complains, saying:

> Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is not generic

Is there another way to assign the correct return type to the snapshot's `data()` method, **before the main code block**?

I am not interested in declaring a new data variable and casting it with the appropriate type.

Comment: I also wish we could do this - seems like a missed opportunity from the firebase team

Answer (score -1):

As stated by your error, the `functions.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot` of the event handler is defined as `QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>`. In regular Firestore SDK use, you change `DocumentData` to something else using the query's [`withConverter(converter)`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/query#_google_cloud_firestore_Query_withConverter_member_2_) method before executing it.

If you want to change `DocumentData` to a different type you have two options:

Option 1: Feed it through a `FirestoreDataConverter`.

```js
import * as firestore from "firebase-admin/firestore";

interface PaymentDocumentInterface {
  /* ... */
}

const paymentDocumentConverter: firestore.FirestoreDataConverter<PaymentDocumentInterface> = {
  toFirestore(post: PaymentDocumentInterface): firestore.DocumentData {
    return { /* ... */ };
  },
  fromFirestore(
    snapshot: firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot,
    options: firestore.SnapshotOptions
  ): PaymentDocumentInterface {
    const data = snapshot.data(options)!;
    return {
      amount: data.amount,
      benefactorDetails: {
        email: data.benefactorDetails.email;
        marketingConsent: data.benefactorDetails.marketingConsent;
      }
    };
  }
};

export const updateDonationProjectAggregations = firestore.document('protectedEnvironmentData/financialData/payments/{paymentId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => { // let this line type itself
    // data will be typed as PaymentDocumentInterface
    const data = paymentDocumentConverter.fromFirestore(snapshot, { serverTimestamps: 'none' });
});
```

Option 2: Manually cast it (not recommended, but fine for basic interfaces).

```js
export const updateDonationProjectAggregations = firestore.document('protectedEnvironmentData/financialData/payments/{paymentId}').onCreate(async (rawSnapshot, context) => { // let this line type itself
    const snapshot = rawSnapshot as unknown as QueryDocumentSnapshot<PaymentDocumentInterface>;
    const data = snapshot.data();
});
```

OR

```js
export const updateDonationProjectAggregations = firestore.document('protectedEnvironmentData/financialData/payments/{paymentId}').onCreate(async (rawSnapshot, context) => { // let this line type itself
    const data = rawSnapshot.data() as unknown as PaymentDocumentInterface;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with that import instead which is generic

```
import { QueryDocumentSnapshot } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
```

Comment: That produces other typescript errors: `Argument of type '(snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot<PaymentDocumentInterface>, context: EventContext) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot, context: EventContext) => any'.
  Types of parameters 'snapshot' and 'snapshot' are incompatible.
    Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is not assignable to type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<PaymentDocumentInterface>'.
      Type 'DocumentData' is missing the following properties from type 'PaymentDocumentInterface': benefactorDetails, beneficiaryDetails, paymentDetails`

Comment: You could also try `import {firestore} from 'firebase-functions';` but both gave me no errors when I tried it.